# How to Copy Code/Core system.xml file into Code/local in magento

Tags: admin, magento-community

i wanted some customization in admin panel so i have made changes in

```
   1) "app/code/core/../system.xml file its working fine.
```

But I don't want to change code inside core folder. Because of my version change.

So i like to move that  file into my local folder but its not working

```
 2) "app/code/local/../system.xml" files is not working
```

Can anyone please guide me how to override system.xml file?

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For the `system.xml` files it doesn't work like it does for class files.
The `system.xml` files are collected from the active modules of Magento. Just copying one in `local` folder it doesn't mean it's in a module, because the module declaration file still says that the module belongs to the `core` codepool.
If you want to add new fields to a section or override some of the fields you need to create you own module.
Here is an example of how you can add a new field in the section `Catalog->Frontend` and how you can override one in the same section.
Let's say that your module is called `Easylife_Catalog`.
You will need the following files:
**`app/etc/modules/Easylife_Catalog.xml`** - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Catalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**`app/code/local/Easylife/Catalog/etc/config.xml`** - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Catalog>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Easylife_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**`app/etc/local/Easylife/Catalog/etc/system.xml`** - system->configuration file
Let's say you want to change the `List Mode` field to be available only at global level (no website and store view level). The setting path is `catalog/frontend/list_mode`. Then the `system.xml` will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <catalog><!-- first part of the path -->
            <groups>
                <frontend><!-- second part of the path -->
                    <fields>
                        <list_mode><!-- third part of the path -->
                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website><!-- this will override the core value -->
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store><!-- this will override the core value -->
                        </list_mode>
                    </fields>
                </frontend>
            </groups>
        </catalog>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Now let's say you want to add a new field called `custom` in the same config section. Now the xml above becomes

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <catalog><!-- first part of the path -->
            <groups>
                <frontend><!-- second part of the path -->
                    <fields>
                        <list_mode><!-- third part of the path -->
                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website><!-- this will override the core value -->
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store><!-- this will override the core value -->
                        </list_mode>
                        <custom translate="label"><!-- your new field -->
                            <label>Custom</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </custom>
                    </fields>
                </frontend>
            </groups>
        </catalog>
    </sections>
</config>
```

I don't know if there is a method to remove some field from the configuration using this method. I looked for it but didn't find anything.

Comment: Thanks. I have only little note, tag <depends> is not necessary, because local modules are always loaded after core modules.

Comment: @JiříChmiel. Ehum...no they are not. all the module declaration files  (`app/etc/modules`) are loaded, then all the `<depends>`  tags are parsed and an hierarchy of modules is established. then the modules are loaded in that order.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  For me, the <depends> in the app/etc/modules/Easylife_Catalog.xml is what I was missing.  Without that it seemed to favor the core system.xml file over the changes in my local system.xml file for modifying declarations.