# How to change Authorize.net orders to Pending instead of Processing

Tags: order-status, authorize.net

Under System > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods > Authorize.net > New Order Status, the only option available creates new orders with the status of "Processing".

How can you change the status to be "Pending" or "New" instead?

Answer (score 3):

As stated [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/52646/), you can change the source model for this variable.

However, instead of changing a core file, create a new module or use an existing one (if it makes sense to do so) and override the variable in your module's `system.xml` file. [Here is how to do that.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9852/how-to-copy-code-core-system-xml-file-into-code-local-in-magento)

A `system.xml` file used only for this purpose would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <sections>
        <payment>
            <groups>
                <authorizenet translate="label" module="paygate">
                    <fields>
                        <order_status translate="label">
                            <label>New Order Status</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_order_status_new</source_model>
                            <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </order_status>
                    </fields>
                </authorizenet>
            </groups>
        </payment>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Comment: If your "Order Process Mode" is "Authorize and capture" then you should not set status to new