# Set "minimum order amount" per store view

Tags: orders, configuration, ce-1.8.1.0

I'm looking for a way/extension to set the **minimum order amount** *per store view*.

It is an existing webshop, which already has a big customer file. This makes it a problem to implement an extension that allows different **minimum order amounts** *per customer group*.

At this moment it is only possible to set the **minimum order amount** per *store*, but not per *store view*. However, the shop I'm working on has two languages set within the same shop. For the language for people living outside of the native country, I would like to set a (different) **minimum order amount**, since that needs to be sent abroad most of the time.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Login as admin, then go to **System->configuration**, then select **‘Sales‘** from left Nav and click on **‘Minimum order amount‘.**
Then select Yes from Enable dropdown, enter Minimum order amount, enter message and also enter error message that will be shown whenever the order will be less than specified amount at the shopping cart.

Thanks.

Comment: That is completely correct, except for one little point: That sets it for a *store*, but not a *store view*. *Store* is the second level, *store view* is the third level. I need to set it for the third level, which isn't possible by default.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the scope of the minimum amount setting.  For that you need a new module with a `system.xml` file that contains the same path to the minimum amount field and just changes the `<show_in_store>` value.
Complete explanation can be found here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/9855/146