# 'Bank Transfer Payment' Sort Order setup for each store view

Tags: payment-methods, sorting

I want to setup different sort order for 'Bank Transfer Payment' payment method

I found sort order option is only available on Default store view, not each language store view

[image]

This is a language store view, there is no option for 'Sort Order'

[image: This is a language store view, there is no option for 'Sort Order']

How can I make to setup sort order option for each store view?

Magento 1.8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom module and change the scope of the sort order. The `system.xml` files of all modules are merged into a big xml, so you need to change in your module `<show_in_website>` and `<show_in_store>` values for the payment method you need.
A complete explanation can  be found here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/9855/146