# Contact form emails to multiple recipients

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-us

I am trying to find a way to send emails sent by the contact form to multiple email addresses but all the solutions I found involve the edit of the core files and I would like to avoid it. I think that the best way would to extend the contact form but I have no idea on how to do that. Anyone has a clue on how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the `IndexController.php` in the `Contacts` module, you'll see a `->sendTransactional` line in the `postAction()` method.

The 3rd parameter (`Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT)`) can be an array of email addresses.

So the only thing you need to do is extend the controller (how to do this can be found here for example: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller

And then add multiple email address to your sendTransactional code:

```
$mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                    ->sendTransactional(
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                        array('emailone@domain.com','emailtwo@domain.com'),
                        null,
                        array('data' => $postObject)
                    );
```

Comment: I also overrode the system.xml file in etc folder to remove the email-validation for the "recipient_email" field

Answer (score 0):

For remove validation from contact email option
Please follow that tips

1. Go here /app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/etc/system.xml
2. find   ,here section you will get validate tag and remove validate-email from validate tag.

You will be happy doing this because i have done same task using that.

Comment: You shouldn't edit core. To override, see http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/9855/5390