# Why is the payment method Cash On Delivery not activatable by store view (show_in_store)?

Tags: system.xml, cash-on-delivery

I mean activate the payment method, not change the title or label, because that is possible.

Lets say I just want our storeview Australia to allow this payment method but none of our other store views, I can not do this without hacking or writing a custom module.

It's the same with the Customer Prefix Options, which you can not edit on a store view basis, which I find extremely irritating.

Is there any specific reason this is not done by default in the system.xml in the core module code? Why would the developers decide not to allow this on a store basis?

```
<cashondelivery translate="label">
                    <label>Cash On Delivery Payment</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </active>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Payment methods are ted to product prices.
Prices can have the scope global or website because it seams natural not to have the customer pay a different price just because he browses the website on a different language.
Same goes for payment methods. It's not normal to restrict a payment method just because the user browses a website on a different language.
This is not a development restriction. it exists because of logical and moral reasons.

The same idea is behind the customer prefix. Since the customer accounts are website or global scoped it does not seam logical to have different settings regarding the name at store view level.
If you really insist in having different values at store view level, [take a look at this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/9855/146) it shows you how to allow or restrict a config setting to as scope.

Comment: Oh ok, so it's more of a configuration error to set up different languages as store views if in actuality you mean the country that language is spoken in. So one should rather set up a new website for each country in which I configure a different language.

Comment: @tecjam. Yes. I think it's a better approach to have different websites if you need to change what you want to change.