# Set a minimum order amount for paypal checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

Although I have set the minimum order in system > configuration > sales, it does not prevent the customer from ordering with the "Check out with Paypal" button.
Is there anyway to include this checkout option in the minimum rule?

Comment: You need to create a shopping cart rule  with no coupon and condition should look like screen shot provided. screen shot link is http://www.amanweb.in/payment.jpg

Comment: @aman_uni This would work for a discount, I need to set a minimum order amount.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the scope of the minimum amount setting.  For that you need a new module with a `system.xml` file that contains the same path to the minimum amount field and just changes the `<show_in_store>` value.
Complete explanation can be found here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/9855/146